# Sending a html input box variable back to codebhind

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I have the following setup.

```
 <table>
      <tr>
           <td>
                <%getScheduleTable("LineNumber", rate, count);%>
           </td>
      </tr>
 </table>
```

`getScheduleTable(line, rate, count)` goes and builds a table inside of this `<td>`

Line number is a literal, but the rate and count will fluctuate. How can I assign the values of the html input boxes elsewhere on the form to `rate` and `count`?

There are probably a couple thousand questions that answer this, but I can't find them probably because I don't know what the `<% %>` operation is actually called.

Does it need to be wrapped in Javascript first somehow? Should I be using something else? I might be able to use datagrid, but I need to put a calculated value in the right most column. I'd prefer not to, because I'm almost done and I feel like I'm just one small step away here. I could be wrong and will do what's needed though.

Thanks!

EDIT: The html control's value will be changed by another process. I'm building a simulation of my page to test. When the site is live, I have no control over the element so I just need to grab the value of that box. It can't be changed to a server control unless I hacked an invisible server helper textbox maybe that's my answer?

Comment: Where is html inputbox?

Comment: On the page above the code. There is stuff in the middle. It's a standard issue html input. `<input id="countThisLine" />`

Answer (score 1):

You can make your `td` and `input` server accessible by adding `runat="server"` and assign them an `id` to access them in code behind.

*Html*

```
<input id="countThisLine" runat="server" />
<table>
      <tr>
           <td id="td1" runat="server">

           </td>
      </tr>
 </table>
```

*In code behind*

```
td.InnerHtml = getScheduleTable(countThisLine.Value, txt, count);
```

Comment: Ok, I did a bad job explaining. Sorry guys see edit. (But that would work for the simulation) +1